# Mui how to change the css of tab and select state

Tags: css, material-ui

I'm trying to change the focus state of the following custom mui component I made. Whenever I tab and select a saved email input, the background is white and I'd like to change it to transparent. Is it possible?

Here's what I have:

```
import { InputAdornment, TextField, TextFieldProps } from "@mui/material";
import { FieldProps } from "formik";

const InputField: React.FC<FieldProps & TextFieldProps> = ({
  field,
  form,
  error,
  ...props
}) => {
  return (
    <TextField
      {...field}
      {...props}
      error={error}
      InputProps={{
        startAdornment: (
          <InputAdornment position="start">
            {props.type === "tel" && (
              <span
                style={{
                  color: error ? "#d32f2f" : "#12efc8",
                }}
              >
                $
              </span>
            )}
          </InputAdornment>
        ),
      }}
      sx={{
        width: "247.56px",
        "& .MuiInputBase-root": {            <------------------
          "&.focus": {                       <------------------
            backgroundColor: "transparent",  <------------------
          },                                 <------------------
        },
      }}
      inputProps={{
        sx: {
          color: error ? "#d32f2f" : "#12efc8",
          "&.focus": { backgroundColor: "transparent" },
        },
      }}
      InputLabelProps={{ sx: { color: "#12efc8" } }}
    />
  );
};

export default InputField;
```